# Possible Bug in the Select InterfaceDist Command

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am new to using SQL. I was wondering whether there could be a bug in this program.

```
/* Insert to interface table all atoms that have diffASA>0*/
insert into NinterfaceAtom(PDB,Chain,Residue,ResId,Symbol,atom,diffASA)
select PDB,Chain,Residue,ResId,Symbol,Atom,max(ASA)-min(ASA) from perAtomASA
group by PDB,Chain,Residue,ResId,Symbol,Atom
having stddev(ASA)>0;
/* Insert to interface table all atoms that have enough distance */
insert ignore into NinterfaceAtoms (PDB,Chain,Residue,ResId,Symbol,atom)
select asa.PDB,asa.Chain,asa.Residue,asa.ResId,asa.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist
inner join
    perAtomASA asa
on
    dist.PDB=asa.PDB and
    dist.Chain=asa.Chain and
    dist.ResId=asa.ResId and
    dist.Symbol=asa.Symbol and
    Seperated=0
```

I am just unsure why the programmmer before me put asa.PDB instead of dist.PDB in the inner join section. 
I was thinking the eighth line needed to be changed from:

```
select asa.PDB,asa.Chain,asa.Residue,asa.ResId,asa.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist
```

to:

```
select dist.PDB,dist.Chain,dist.Residue,dist.ResId,dist.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist
```

Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. If you are doing an inner join, then both columns (`asa.PDB` and `dist.PDB`) have the same value, right?

Comment: You mean this line dist.PDB=asa.PDB right? Why is this looking like a bug for you?

Comment: There's no bug. The JOIN is being done in part on the values in `asa.PDB` and `dist.PDB` being the same. There's no bug - that's perfectly valid and understandable SQL. What part of *they match if dist.PDB = asa.PDB* plus other conditions would you think is a *bug*?

Comment: The edits in my question I added might clear where I think there is a bug.

Comment: If both `PDB` columns are the same (which the INNER JOIN says they will be), it doesn't matter which one is in the columns list in the SELECT. Think about it. if both `asa.PDB` and `dist.POB` are the same, either one will work.

Comment: So it works for the asa variable to be used before it is defined?

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. You are not explaining why the old code is a problem. You don't say what the code should do or even give an example of input & desired output, so how can we possbly know what is correct? Please also make clear what the difference is between those long lines. Please format all that code reasonably. PS As others have said, the suggested select values are all restricted to be equal to the original select vaules, so your suggestion changes nothing. What intro to SQL are you using?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. What does "asa variable" mean? Before what is defined? What definition? "Before" in what process? You don't seem to understand how a SELECT statement works. If you don't understand the answers then comment on them re the first thing you don't understand. (Also see my edited last comment.) The "conceptual" evaluation of a SELECT statement evaluates the SELECT clause last.

Comment: Use @ immediately before a user name to have that user notified of a comment if they are neither the poster nor the only non-commenter. Google 'stackexchange notifications'.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining `asa` and `dist`. It is perfectly logical that their values are checked to make sure only matching pairs will be in the result. So, unless you have a very good reason to think that in the line

```
dist.PDB=asa.PDB
```

you need `dist.PDB` instead of `asa.PDB`, the command looks to be correct. And if this would be correct

```
dist.PDB=dist.PDB
```

then it would be trivial and it would be pointless to have this part checked at all. When you identify bugs, you either need to see behavioral problems of the software, or to understand the code you are looking at.

EDIT

In the select clause one can use `asa.PDB` or `dist.PDB`, because the two are equal because of the `on` condition which ensured their equality. If the two are different, then the pair will not be in the result. So, in terms of values, it makes no difference. But if it is more intuitive to have `dist.PDB` in the `select`, then you might want to change it (there is no harm in it, because the value is exactly the same) so the code will be more readable and later, if the code is changed and the two will no longer have to be equal, you will not have new bugs out of the blue sky.

Comment: To be clear, I am trying to change the eighth line of code to the following code: 'select asa.PDB,asa.Chain,asa.Residue,asa.ResId,asa.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist'

Comment: @BenOppenheimer you mean the select clause, the line of select asa.PDB,asa.Chain,asa.Residue,asa.ResId,asa.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist ?

Comment: That is correct. I didn't show what I was going to change I mean to change it to:  select dist.PDB,dist.Chain,dist.Residue,dist.ResId,dist.Symbol,dist.Atom from interfaceDist dist

Comment: @BenOppenheimer I have edited my answer accordingly. It is not a bug, since it is equivalent with your intention, but if the change makes it more logical, then I suggest that you should do it.

Comment: @BenOppenheimer you are welcome. If this answered the question, then you might consider accepting the answer.